# Facing Deadlock since enabling Tomcat Connection Pool

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

We were using tomcat resource to connect to our MySQL 5.7 data base, the connection string is given below,

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/bm" 
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
           factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
           initialSize="34"
           maxActive="500"   
           maxIdle="5"  
           username="root" 
           testWhileIdle="true"  
           removeAbandonedTimeout="60"  
           maxWait="-1" 
           removeAbandoned="true" 
           logAbandoned="true"
           validationQuery="select 1" 
           validationInterval="60000"
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
           password="XXXXXX" 
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="120000"
           testOnBorrow="true"             
           url="TESTURL"/>
```

While this was working fine, we started facing the issue of no port avialble at the OS level. Hence we switched to tomcat connection pooling,

```
<Resource name="jdbc/bm" 
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
            **factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"** 
       initialSize="34"
           maxActive="500"   
           maxIdle="5"  
           username="root" 
           testWhileIdle="true"  
           removeAbandonedTimeout="60"  
           maxWait="-1" 
           removeAbandoned="true" 
           logAbandoned="true"
   validationQuery="select 1" 
           validationInterval="60000"
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="120000"
           testOnBorrow="true"             
           url="URL/>
```

Since we introduced this we are frequently getting the following error in our logs,

```
 2017-Aug-02 01:23:48,426 ERROR IRWorkflowService:3446 - ^M
  org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Hibernate 
   operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL
```

We are using SPRING-HIBERNATE based connection setting. We have checked all the code for a possible deadlock scenerio but are not getting any clue.

**EDIT**

I did read up on this one [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230341/cannotacquirelockexception-spring-hibernate-mysql), but they don't seem similar. I am getting this error even on tables which are not showing locked in show engine InnoDB status. For example, the lock displayed in show engine InnoDB status shows a table locked at X time on Y table, but the exception is newer than X time and on a different table altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CannotAcquireLockException (Spring, Hibernate, Mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230341/cannotacquirelockexception-spring-hibernate-mysql)

Comment: I did read up on this one, but nothing pointed there is the problem. I am getting this error even on tables which are not showing locked in show engine InnoDB status. For example, the lock displayed in show engine InnoDB status shows a table locked at X time on Y table, but the exception is newer than X time and on a different table altogether.

Comment: Why do you use maxWait="-1" which will wait infinite time? have you tried with default 30000 ?

Comment: We have removed the Factory = "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" and for now it's working fine. But need to debug more to figure out why the factory and MySql JAR are causing this.

Comment: @CoolTechie I encountered the exact same issue and removing the factory "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" solved the issue. Do you remember why adding this factory was causing problems?